# array inside object is not defined JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, twig

I have this object example:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "name",
    "address": "add",
    "contactsArr": [{
        "id": 1,
        "name": "cont",
        "tel": "tel",
        "mail": "mail"
    }],
    "description": "desc"
}
```

this object is inside an array of objects, the array is called `arrSuppCompNames`. I get this array from a JSON string inside a DB table.
here is my function to get the last object's id inside `contactsArr`:

```
function getLastIdFromArrContUser(){
  if("{{user.supplier_comp_name}}" != null && "{{user.supplier_comp_name}}" != "" && "{{user.supplier_comp_name}}" != 0){//not first
    var arrSuppCompNames = JSON.parse(("{{user.supplier_comp_name}}").replace(/&quot;/g,'"'));
    console.log("arrSuppCompNames: " + JSON.stringify(arrSuppCompNames));
    return arrSuppCompNames[arrSuppCompNames.length - 1].contactsArr[contactsArr.length - 1].id;
  }else{//first
    return 0;
  }
}
```

but I keep getting `Uncaught ReferenceError: contactsArr is not defined` in this line `return arrSuppCompNames[arrSuppCompNames.length - 1].contactsArr[contactsArr.length - 1].id;`. the thing is I know for sure that `contactsArr` exists inside the array of objects because of the log print just a line before. this is my log:

```
arrSuppCompNames: [{"id":1,"name":"name","address":"add","contactsArr":[{"id":1,"name":"cont","tel":"tel","mail":"mail"}],"description":"desc"}]
```

Don't know if it's just a stupid JS error or mistype I can't see or something more JSON related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your try to access index [contactsArr.length - 1] but contactsArr is not defined in this context. Consider:

```
var contactsArr = arrSuppCompNames[arrSuppCompNames.length - 1].contactsArr;
return contactsArr[contactsArr.length - 1].id;
```

Comment: Thanks it solved my problem.. although I still didn't get why it is a mistake in the first place

Comment: contactsArr was only an index name in your JSON structure and not defined in the scope of your function. What I suggested was saving the array from the JSON structure to a local variable which name is then known in the scope. An alternative would have been: `return arrSuppCompNames[arrSuppCompNames.length - 1].contactsArr[arrSuppCompNames[arrSuppCompNames.length - 1].contactsArr.length - 1].id`

Answer (score 0):

Based on your example I don't think you need to specify the index on `contactsArr`.  It should just be `return arrSuppCompNames[arrSuppCompNames.length - 1].contactsArr.id;`

Answer (score 0):

You can use destructing assignment to get `"contactsArr"` property value array containing `"id"` property

```js
var arrSuppCompNames = [{
    "id": 2,
    "name": "name",
    "address": "add",
    "contactsArr": [{
      "id": 2,
      "name": "cont",
      "tel": "tel",
      "mail": "mail"
    }],
    "description": "desc"
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "name",
    "address": "add",
    "contactsArr": [{
      "id": 1,
      "name": "cont",
      "tel": "tel",
      "mail": "mail"
    }],
    "description": "desc"
  }
]

var {contactsArr: [{id}]} = arrSuppCompNames[arrSuppCompNames.length - 1];
console.log(id);
```